# Python BeautifulSoup HTML Parsing to get Text

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML page that is formed like the following

```
<section class="entry-content">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</section>
```

I am trying to pull the text that is contained in the `<p>`tags using BeautifulSoup/Python.  This is what I have so far, but I am not sure how to "dig down" to the `<p>` tags and get the text.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    url = 'URL'
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(data)

    ingreds = bs.find('section', {'class': 'entry-content'})

    fname = 'most.txt'
    with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write('\n'.join(ingreds))

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can 'dig down' and get the text out of a tag with the `.stripped_strings` iterable:

```
section = bs.find('section', {'class': 'entry-content'})
ingreds = [' '.join(ch.stripped_strings) for ch in section.find_all(True)]
```

We use `.find_all(True)` to only loop over tags contained in `section`, not the direct text content (such as newlines).

Note that `.find_all(True)` will go over any nested tags, which could result in string duplication. The following will only loop over direct tags of `section`:

```
ingreds = [' '.join(ch.stripped_strings) for ch in section if hasattr(ch, 'stripped_strings')]
```

Comment: I think `bs.find` may return a mixture of `NavigableString` and `Tag`s. Only the `Tag`s will have the `stripped_strings` attribute.

Comment: I'd just like to pick your brain on how to handle this: If we have `<p>foo<b>BAR</b></p>` then [the above code](http://ideone.com/2wiT4D) will produce `'BAR'` twice. You can get around the problem [like this](http://ideone.com/Z4xHrv), but I'm not particularly pleased with having to use `isinstance`. Do you know a better way? (I like lxml+XPath because you do not have to fuss with all this stuff.)

Comment: I get an error when I try this: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: @ddroboul: Did you assign `None` to `.find_all()` or `bs.find()`?

Comment: @unutbu: Bah, humbug. Okay, I'd go for a loop over `section` and use `if hasattr(ch, 'stripped_strings')` then. BeautifulSoup has it's flaws, this is one of them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm not sure what you mean by your above comment.  Can you be a little more verbose.  Pardon the ignorance, I'm very new to programming in general.

Comment: @ddroboul: I had tested the examples; nothing in that code should raise such a `TypeError`; I tried to diagnose why you did get that error. In any case, If I use your example `section`, the above code works.